# Bash function does not work recurrsively

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, wildcards, function

**Directory Structure:**

one.pdf
./subdir/two.pdf
./anothersubdir/three.pdf

When I type:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.pdf"
```

it retrieves all the pdfs, including subdirectories.

**Bash Function**

```
function getext {find ./ -type f -name "$1"}
```

With this function in bashrc, typing:

```
getext *.pdf
```

It only retrieves "one.pdf" but not the rest.

*Question*: what happens here with the function? What's missing from it compared to standard input to only get the first file and stop?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Apart from everything else, your function contains a syntax error. There's a missing `;` (or newline) before the closing `}`.

Comment: I know the role of the semi-colon in general and had this function contained anything else I would have used it. But can you help me understand why this works as it is? A syntax error should prevent it from working but it does not in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same reason that you quote `"*.pdf"` in the arguments to `find` *inside* your function, you need to quote it when you *call* the function:

```
getext "*.pdf"
```

Otherwise, the shell will attempt to match `*.pdf` to filenames in the current directory resulting in it being expanded - in this case to `one.pdf` - *before* being passed to your function.